# issue storing information into variable in C

Tags: c, variables, storage, scanf

I wrote the following code for an intro to C class.  However for some reason I cannot figure out why the `scanf` will not store the input into the fahrenheit variable therefore not allowing me to do the calculation correctly.  I switched the starting value from 0 to 212 to make sure that my calculation is correct however it still doesn't allow me to update.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main(void){

 double fahrenheit = 212.00;
 double celcius = 0;

 //prompt the user for the information                                                 
 printf("Enter a temperature in degrees Fahrenheit >");

 //store the information in the Fahrenheit var.                                        
 scanf("%f", &fahrenheit);
 //calculate the change in metrics                                                     
 celcius = (fahrenheit-32)*.5556 ;
 printf("%f degrees Fahrenheit is equal to %f degrees       celcius\n",fahrenheit,celcius);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper `printf` and `scanf` format to use with `double` argument is `%lf`. Not `%f`, but `%lf`. Don't use `%f` with `double`. It should be

```
scanf("%lf", &fahrenheit);
...
printf("%lf degrees Fahrenheit is equal to %lf degrees celcius\n",
  fahrenheit, celcius);
```

Note that `%f` will work with `double` in `printf` (not in `scanf`), but using it in that fashion is still a bad habit, which only fuels the popular beginner's misconception that `printf` and `scanf` are somehow "inconsistent" in that regard.

The matching between format specifiers and argument types is well-defined and consistent between `printf` and `scanf`:

- `%f` is for `float`
- `%lf` is for `double`
- `%Lf` is for `long double`.

Answer (score 0):

You declared your variable as `double fahrenheit;` but used the `scanf()` specifier for `float`, try this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float fahrenheit = 212.00;
  /* ^ float, instead of double */
    float celcius    = 0;

    // prompt the user for the information
    printf("Enter a temperature in degrees Fahrenheit > ");

    // store the information in the Fahrenheit var.
    if (scanf("%f", &fahrenheit) != 1) // check that scanf succeeded
        return -1;
    // calculate the change in metrics
    celcius = (fahrenheit-32)*.5556 ;
    printf("%f degrees Fahrenheit is equal to %f degrees celcius\n",fahrenheit,celcius);
    return 0;
}
```

or change the `scanf()` specifier to `"%lf"` the `printf()` specifier is ok for both.

Also, you better make sure `scanf()` succeeded reading.

Answer (score 0):

You're reading a float (with `%f`) and yet you're storing it inside a `double`.

Either

1. Change the type of `fahrenheit` to float
2. Change your `scanf` call to `scanf("%lf", &fahrenheit);